# How to extract useful information from BSOD (Blue Screen of Death) dump files?

Tags: windows, windows-10, dump

I'm part of endpoint administration and after migrating to windows 10, we see lot of BSOD.

Having hard time from users complaining on this.

we have created few setup from SCCM to collect the dump files in a central location(some day as low as 10 and on some day we see as high as 300 instances.) and is there any automated ways to generate a report from the dump files with information like build version, device model, Bug check string, bugcheck code, crashing driver etc.

So that we can focus on the top priority item.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered software tool called "[WhoCrashed](https://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed)" which analyses BSODs and Crashes local PCs? I've been using it for years for my personal use. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.